# Moment Timezone : I don't understand how default timezones work

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

Say it's 10:00am in my local time, America/Denver. When I set the default timezone in moment timezone:

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/Chicago");
```

Current time objects are printed out in the correct timezone, America Chicago:

```
moment().toString(); // returns 11:00am
```

However, when I parse in a date, for example:

```
// exampleTime equal to 9:05am, already in America/Chicago
var parsedTime = moment(exampleTime, "HH:mm")
```

It seems to take the date, parse it in the local timezone ("America/Denver") and then "convert" it to America/Chicago. So, when I:

```
parsedTime.toString(); //prints ~10:05am
```

It prints out a time that is an hour ahead of what it should be.

Do I have to specify the timezone of every time I parse in? Why wouldn't it parse in the default timezone?

Comment: if you want to mess with timezones, you should probably use `moment.tz()` instead.

Comment: I'm using moment.tz to specify the default timezone. I'm wondering why parsing in a date, then, would parse in the local timezone and get converted rather than being parsed in the default timezone.

Comment: well, try `moment.tz(exampleTime, "HH:mm", 'America/Chicago')` and see if that leaves the hours unchanged.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but it seems to defeat the purpose of having a default timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using it correctly, you're just hitting on a bug.  It's already been logged in [this issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/197), and there's a [pending fix here](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/217).